# Why does Windows Explorer highlight only second entry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, selection

Why does Windows Explorer highlight the second but never the first entry if I use the keyboard for navigation?

Example: let's look at a folder that contains the following entries

- a1
- a2
- a3
- b1
- b2

If I hit `a` on the keyboard, the explorer highlights entry 'a2' instead of 'a1'. It works fine for `b` with 'b1' (because it's not the first entry).

Similarly, if I open a folder and use the <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> key to navigate then the first entry is skipped again. Why?!

It's probable that I'm too stupid for this but this "feature" really annoys me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter a folder the first time, the focus is "hidden" at the first item without actually selecting it (actually I don't know the real thing happens under the hood, but that's the idea), so when pressing <kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> button, it will select the next entry.

If you need to *select* the first one, press <kbd>Space</kbd>. To *deselect* at any places, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: That is the correct answer (I've also checked the same results). As to why Microsoft designed it as that...

Comment: Yay! Space is the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: (I would up-vote the answer if I had the enough reputation.)

Comment: @normanius To highlight the first or the last item regardless of the current selection you can use the Home or End key, respectively.

Comment: @and31415 Home does not really work to highlight the first entry (at least on Win7). The first entry (as Lưu Vĩnh Phúc pointed out) is selected, but not highlighted. I have to hit space to also highlight it. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @and31415 it wouldn't work the first time you enter a folder. The only way is using space. It only works if you come back from a child folder in windows Vista and above

Comment: This has driven me insane for the longest time, as I very frequently use the keyboard for navigation... I had no idea it was such a simple solution. Kind of annoying that it's two button presses for the first item, though. Oh well!